# How to use Camel convertBodyTo with a list

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a list of type A and I would like to transform it in a list of type B.

Let's imagine:

```java
// ... call the db and get a few rows mapped to List<A>
.to("jdbc:...")
.convertBodyTo(List.class) // ?!?
```

In Camel, if it was a "normal" type, I would just use: `.convertBodyTo(B.class)`, then let Camel find the converter I coded.

However, since this is a list of type A, if I do `.convertBodyTo(List.class)`, the converter is just not called.

I could not split and process one at the time, because I need to do some grouping on `List<A>` before converting.

I could fix it by using a bean, but I wanted to know if there is any way to call `convertBodyTo` to convert from a list to a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into how to write your own Type Converters [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/type-converter.html#_writing_your_own_type_converters), but I don't believe they will work in your case due to Java's type erasure. As you alluded to, you'll just be converting a `List` to a `List`.

Personally I'd probably just implement a [`Processor`](https://camel.apache.org/manual/processor.html) and call [`.process(..)`](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/eips/process-eip.html). It's a bit neater than `.bean(..)` for this use case.

Comment: IMHO a `transformer` (https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/eips/transform-eip.html) would be even better (more meaningful) than a simple `Processor`. My 2 cents